# Maximal matching without weights

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

I'm studying for a graph theory exam. And while looking at some exams of previous years **which were handed out by the professor**, I found the following question.

[image: Consider the bipartite graph G below: (unweighted bipartite graph). (a) Construct a maximal matching of G of size exactly 3.]

As I understand it, a maximal matching is a matching with the highest possible weight, but this graph doesn't display weights.

The next part of the question, not shown in the image, asks for a maximum matching, given the initial matching from (a), which I know how to construct using augmenting paths.

Comment: They mean maximal with respect to the number of edges. In other words, take the weight of each edge to be $1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The important word here is maximal (that is the reason that the 'al' is underlined). You do not want a matching of maximum size. This could not have size 3 because for example the edges ag, bh, ci, and df are independent.

The idea in this exercise is, that you want to find 3 edges that are independent (and thus form a matching) but at the same time all other edges need to be incident with at least one of those 3.

In the picture the vertices e and j are cut off (I suppose), if they are adjacent, the 3 edges bg, di, and ej seem to be a maximal matching:

They clearly form an independent set and each of a, c, f, and h has neighbours only in {b, d, e, g, i, j}.